# Sending error message from back to front (php+html)

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I have an impression I'm missing something really simple and obvious:

I'm sending the response back to front from my php file with GET :

Add.php:

```
foreach ($quote as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value) or !isset($value)) {
        $error = "$key field is empty";
    }
}

if (!empty($error)) {
    // send error message to front
    $url = "index.php?error=". urlencode($error);
    header("Location:$url");
    exit;
}
```

and I can actually see in the debugger that index.php gets this variable and it goes through the code, but my div still isn't displayed on the page :

Index.php:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>some text here</h1>
    <div class="alert alert-success success my-3" style="display:none">Done!</div>
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo(<<<EOT
        <div class="alert alert-danger fail my-3">{$_GET['error']}</div>
        EOT);
    }
?>
```

Success messages is handled with AJAX:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    /**
    * Send data after click on submit button
    */
    $(function() {
        $("#add").on('submit', function(e) {

            // stop the following function from happening before click on submit button
            e.preventDefault();

            // send ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'add.php',
                data: $("#add").serialize(),
                type: "post",
                success: function(response) {
                    // check server response
                    if (response == "success") {
                        // show success
                        $('.success').fadeIn(500);
                        setTimeout(function () { location.reload() }, 1000);
                    }
                    //else {
                        // show error message on failure
                    //    $('.fail').fadeIn(1000);
                    //}
                }
            });
        });
    });
})

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: how many files are you using ? name of front end and backend file?

Comment: index.php for front and add.php for back

Comment: show the complete code from those file. if its too much code then show precisely.

Comment: I've edited the question with some more details, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your index.php with the below one.

```
if (isset($_GET['error']))
{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger my-3">'.$_GET['error'].'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your URL after the first render/serve.
Like this:

```
<code>
   if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo(<<<EOT
        <div class="alert alert-danger my-3">{$_GET['error']}</div>
        EOT);
    //need this line
        unset($error);
    }
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty then, the problem was in AJAX, I just added the error/success handling with PHP instead and it worked!

```
    if (isset($_GET['success']))
{
    echo('<div class="alert alert-success success my-3">Done!</div>');
}
```

Thank you guys for your help